# React native Bottom curved Navigation

Tags: react-native, bottomnavigationview

I am using this library react-native-curved-bottom-bar for bottom tabs but there is  one issue when I switch between different screens all screens components re render
my question is that why it's rerender an if this is re render then how can i stops that screens from re rendering.

I am expecting that it will not re render all screen.